# Vuejs display other input fields based on selected value from dropdown

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I have a select dropdown list and two hidden input fields. I would like when a user select first item in dropdown list , the first input field gets displayed and vice versa.
Here is my code but I'm not sure how to do an if statement so when selected value equals xxx display input field 1, else display input field 2

```
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
               selected: ''
             }
       });
<select name="parent" class="form-control" v-model="selected" required>
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="item1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="item2">Item 2</option>
</select>
<div>
   <input name="Test 1" v-show="selected"> //display when item 1 is selected
</div>
<div>
   <input name="Test 2" v-show="selected"> //display when item 2 is selected
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do something like

```
<div v-if="selected === 'item1'">
  item1 was selected
</div>
<div v-else>
  Something else was selected.
</div>
```

If you don't want to use `v-else` you can do:

```
<div v-if="selected != 'item1'">
  Something besides item1 was selected
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to be able to help!

Comment: this is a very nice way of handling, but what if you have a variable amount of options, and you know that the first is the one you can use to filter.. how do you identify that first option?